PowerBI DAX Min Measure - error message "A single value for column 'PerformanceValue' in the table 'National KPI Upload 13' cannot be determined
I'm trying to get the minimum value against specific measures in a column in a table, using the DAX as below, but getting an error ""A single value for column 'PerformanceValue' in the table 'National KPI Upload 13' cannot be determined...This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count or sum to get a single result"
My code:
Min Performance =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'National KPI Upload 13'[PerformanceValue] ),
    FILTER (
        'National KPI Upload 13',
        'National KPI Upload 13'[Measure]
            = EARLIER ( 'National KPI Upload 13'[Measure] )
    )
)

The error is against the last part, posted here in italics

Don't use EARLIER function at all - it's obsolete. Use variables instead.

As the documentation says:

EARLIER succeeds if there is a row context prior to the beginning of the table scan. Otherwise it returns an error.

If you are trying to create a measure, you don't have a row context, so the earlier won't work.
Without some more information about the data and the semantic model, it is difficult to say how to solve the problem, but you can try to use the MINX() function. You can find some moreinfo here.
